# Images aren't showing when using functions for a traffic light sequence in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, while-loop

I'm trying to make a traffic light sequence using functions so it continuously loops. The original image used in the beginning shows, which tells me it not the links that aren't working.

the console also shows the text that I'm sending to it so the functions are running too but the image doesn't change.

Could anyone explain to me why this might be happening please? Everything I've done seems to be correct, I've tried it in different browsers and tried to debug it the best I can.

Thanks.

**JS**

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}

function reset(){
    greenGo = 'turn green light on and red man';
    console.log(greenGo);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Reset.png';
    sleep(1000);
}

function stopTraffic(){
    wait1 = 'turn amber on and red man';
    console.log(wait1);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Stop_Traffic_1.png';
    sleep(1000);
    wait2 = 'Turn red  on and red man';
    console.log(wait2);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Stop_Traffic_2.png';
    sleep(1000);

}

function startPedestrian(){
    wait1 = 'keep red on turn green man on';
    console.log(wait1);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Start_Ped.png';
    sleep(1000);
}

function startTraffic(){
    wait1 = 'Turn red, amber and red man on';
    console.log(wait1);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Start_Traffic_1.png';
    sleep(1000);
    wait2 = 'Turn Green on and red man';
    console.log(wait2);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Start_Traffic_2.png';
    sleep(1000);
}

function stopPedestrian(){
    wait1 = 'Turn Red on and red man';
    console.log(wait1);
    img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    img.src = 'Stop_Ped.png';
    sleep(1000);
}

function run(){
    setTimeout(reset(),3000);
    input1 = 0;
    while (input1 == '0'){
        console.log('Turn green on and red man');
        stopTraffic();
        stopPedestrian();
        startTraffic();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
        <script src="trafficLights.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Traffic Lights</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="run()">
        <h1>Traffic Lights</h1>
        <img id="traffic_lights" src="" width="100" height="100"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are your images in same directory as the script? And, does it work if you hard code one of the images in the html like that :<img id='traffic_lights' src = 'Start_Ped.png' width = '100' height = '100'/>

Comment: Yes they are and yes they do, i've just tested it and it runs through but it only shows the final image, the delay works on the console. But the images aren't changing.

Comment: I see, maybe you should call asynchronously, with JS events, please see this example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/learn-asynchronous-image-loading-javascript

Comment: Is there a reason for using full CPU loops as a sleeping method instead of promises ? You know your browser is not actually sleeping in that case!

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi what could i use instead of this? can you show me an example please. i'm more familiar  with python than javascript.

Comment: In your `run` function, why are you calling `reset` after 3 seconds then looping indefinitely over the other functions ?

Comment: I've posted an answer, please give it a go and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep` method does not call on the browser to sleep, it actually hangs the browser by looping on the creation of multiple date objects. A better approach to achieving your goal is using timeouts inside of promises, you can read all about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

For your image loading, I believe it is due to the browser hanging with all the code it has to run at once as well as DOM updates being deferred until all processing is done (which will never happen due to your infinite loop).

In the solution below, I present a couple of new functions that will help with code duplication as well as your main loop.

```js
// returns a promise that resolves after the given milliseconds
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
    })
}

// performs an action which seems to repeat consistantly across the functions
function action(img, src, message) {
    console.log(message);
    // img.src = src;
}

/**
 * All functions below return a promise when the sleeps are done
 */
function reset(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        action(img, 'Reset.png', 'Turn green light on and red man');
        sleep(1000).then(resolve);
    });
}
function stopTraffic(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        action(img, 'Stop_Traffic_1.png', 'Turn amber on and red man');
        sleep(1000).then(() => {
            action(img, 'Stop_Traffic_2.png', 'Turn red  on and red man');
            sleep(1000).then(resolve);
        });
    });
    
}
function startPedestrian(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        action(img, 'Start_Ped.png', 'Keep red on turn green man on');
        sleep(1000).then(resolve);
    });
}
function startTraffic(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        action(img, 'Start_Traffic_1.png', 'Turn red, amber and red man on');
        sleep(1000).then(() => {
            action(img, 'Start_Traffic_2.png', 'Turn Green on and red man');
            sleep(1000).then(resolve);
        });
    });
}
function stopPedestrian(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        action(img, 'Stop_Ped.png', 'Turn Red on and red man');
        sleep(1000).then(resolve);
    });
}

// recursive function that loops upon itself indefinitely
function loop(img) {
    console.log('Turn green on and red man');
    stopTraffic(img).then(() => {
        stopPedestrian(img).then(() => {
            startTraffic(img).then(() => {
                loop(img);
            });
        });
    });
}

// main function which sleeps for 3 seconds, resets, then loops
function run() {
    let img = document.getElementById('traffic_lights');
    console.log('Program starts in 3 seconds...');
    sleep(3000).then(() => {
        reset(img).then(() => {
            loop(img);
        })
    });
}

run();
```

I have commented out the image src update in the `action` function for the snippet to work. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/YrJMay) with a full example with images from the internet.

Hope this helps.